# How to recover or rebuilt alfresco themes

Tags: linux, alfresco, alfresco-share, file-recovery, alfresco-wqs

I accidentally deleted the `alfresco-community\tomcat\webapps\share\themes` directory including the `alfresco-community\tomcat\webapps\share\themes\wcmqs.war` file. How do I recover this file or rebuilt a new on linux?

I was able to copy `themes` folder from a new install (windows) but not the `war` file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got to do [this](https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/WQS-install-manual.html):

1. Download the Web Quick Start zip bundle file: alfresco-enterprise-wcmqs-4.2.8.zip
2. Locate Alfresco installation directory. Copy the AMP files into
   the relevant amps directories for Alfresco and Share:

Copy the alfresco-enterprise-wcmqs-4.2.8.amp file to the amps directory.

Copy the alfresco-enterprise-wcmqs-share-4.2.8.amp file to the amps-share directory.

Apply the AMP files for the Tomcat application server, using the apply_amps.sh  file  in `/bin` directory.

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.